# How to deal with this complicated scenario, Problem using (Pandas). any alternative way?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pyspark

**My Scenario:**

- User A is (fraudster).
- User B is not (fraudster). However, the system will not allow user B
  to do any action. Because B and A are using the same Phone
  Number(Shared attribute with Fraud User).(1 layer).
- User D is not (fraudster). But D is using the same Deviceid with B
  and B is sharing attribute with fraud User. Then block User D as well. In this case, there are 2 layers. D compare with B, B compares with A.

**Table:**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import pandas as pd
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='database',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    df = pd.read_sql("select * from tableuser",con=connection)
##
    def expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, col_name):
        t = pd.merge(no_fraud, fraud, on=col_name)
        if len(t):
            df.loc[df.ID.isin(t.ID_x), "IsFraudsterStatus"] = 1
            return True
        return False

    while True:
        added_fraud = False
        fraud = df[df.IsFraudsterStatus == 1]
        no_fraud = df[df.IsFraudsterStatus == 0]
        added_fraud |= expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, "DeviceId")
        added_fraud |= expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, "Email")
        added_fraud |= expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, "MobileNo")
        if not added_fraud:
            break
    print(df)

except Error as e:
    print("Error reading data from MySQL table", e)
finally:
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        connection.close()
        cursor.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Working with 1000row.
Now I have added 500k rows and error message popup

**Error:**

[image]

I have also used recursive CTE for this but it is working with a small data amount only.
May you help me, please? Suggest to me an alternative way to archive it. The expected number of rows is 4 million users. When the user click payment button the system will verify, which means time execution is necessary as well.

Comment: Did you already try to make the database do the work? So for example, if i understood you correctly, just ask the database if there is an entry with the data from the user and if any of these entries has isFraudStatus = 1 decline the user. Like >select * from tableuser where e-mail = 'email' or phone_number = 'phone_number', ...<

Comment: It is not clear what the output that you want. Do you need a dataframe of all users that are not fraudsters but share some characteristics with fraudsters?

Comment: I want to decline the users that shared attributes with Fraudsters user. It could be a direct share Like A & B. Or not Direct Like D & A. I want something to get them all for me. using dataframe or using MySql.

Comment: @Jonas Yes, I have tried it, It is working if direct share only. But in my case user D is not shared with fraudsters. It is shared with another user B, And B is the one who shared with fraudsters user A.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataframe of users that share a characteristics with fraudsters using the Pandas function isin.

For example to get all the users that have the same phone number than a fraudster:

```
fraudsters = df[df["isFraudsterStatus" == 1]
filter = df["MobileNo"].isin(fraudsters["MobileNo"])
non_fraud_with_same_mobile = df[filter]
```

Comment: I am even not able to retrieve the data from the database and assign it to df. 
    df = pd.read_sql("select * from tableuser",con=connection) shows MemoryError.

Comment: You have to use set chunksize when using read_sql, so the memory of your dataframe does not extrapolates the memory available in your machine. So the Pandas dataframe instead of getting all the info and putting in the memory it will only use a smaller part to the dataframe.

Comment: I have used chunksize in the read_sql. However, I will get the same error when trying to use isin function. ?